# Policy regarding mass minor edits

Tags: discussion, editing

Does Chess SE have an internal policy regarding mass edits?

Currently (May 28, 2020), the front page is not in the ideal shape (to put it mildly), and I am unaware of the general "Maintenance Force" initiative.

Should we have such a policy? While improving edits are good, the ones that are minor **should not be done in mass** in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does Chess SE have an internal policy regarding mass edits?

No.

> Currently (May 28, 2020), the front page is not in the ideal shape (to
>   put it mildly)

I have to admit this doesn't affect me because on the "Questions" page there is an option to filter by:

Newest, Active, Bountied, Unanswered, More (Frequent, Votes, Custom)

and I always have "Newest". If there is an option somewhere to have that as the default then sometime in the dim and distant past I made "Newest" my default. I do very occasionally click on one of the others but probably only once a month.

If it disturbs you I suggest you do the same.

Edit: A new poll started to see what everybody thinks. Vote [here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/844/poll-should-we-limit-number-of-edits-to-5-per-day-per-member).