# Poll - Should we limit number of edits to 5 per day per member?

Tags: discussion, editing

Currently there is a built-in limit of 5 pending suggested edits per day. That means that if you don't have full edit privileges that any edits you make go into a pending queue where they have to be approved before going live. If the queue is handled quickly, which it is on this site, then an un-privileged member can make many more than 5 edits per day. Of course a privileged member can make more than 5 edits per day anyway.

So, should we introduce a limit of 5 edits per day for all members (excluding edits to posts which are already on the front page – the main problem with excessive edits is that they bump posts).

Have your say by voting up the next answer "Yes", if you agree, and voting up the answer after that for "No"

Comment: To quote former SE employee [Robert Cartaino](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/100): [Polling is generally not a good substitute for discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Vote). In my opinion, there *should* be an explanation, even for a yes/no answer.

Comment: @double-beep I guess, the discussion can happen [in my original post](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/840/10570) that kind of triggered this poll.

Comment: Would this solve an actual problem the site faces?

Comment: I think it's better for people to write their own answer than vote for one of those two answers. Those answers don't explain a reason. Also, they're going to appear to be better answers than they are under your new system.

Answer (score 20):

NO!

We should not have a limit of 5 edits per member per day.

Comment: As I'm not a regular on this site, I'll leave the poll to the community, but I'll also mention [this guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51768/241919) since limiting 5 edits per member per day is... a very rare proposal compared to: "*Do batches in the span of minutes (added: or hours), like 3 questions at a time*"

Comment: @AndrewT. that guideline is written for a site where the 'size' of the homepage is 3 hours. On Chess.SE, it's more like 3 days.

Comment: I have been creating tag wiki excerpts and retagging questions today and found the limit of five edits very *limiting*. I can't remember running in this limit so quickly on Literature SE, where I edited dozens of tag wiki excerpts per day when I was new there.

Comment: @Tsundoku tag wiki edits are fine anyway, they don't bump posts.

Comment: Absolutely not, sometime we have misspelling, grammar error,... that only realize after posted.

Answer (score 3):

YES!

We should have a limit of 5 edits per member per day.

Comment: For non-established users, this would be a good idea. However, there should be no limits for established users and mods.